# Workaround for lack of 'nameof' operator in C# for type-safe databinding?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

There has been a lot of sentiment to include a `nameof` operator in C#. As an example of how this operator would work, `nameof(Customer.Name)` would return the string `"Name"`.

I have a domain object. And I have to bind it. And I need names of properties as strings then. And I want them to be type-safe.

I remember coming across a workaround in .NET 3.5 which provided the functionality of `nameof` and involved lambda expressions. However, I have not been able to locate this workaround. Can anyone provide that workaround to me?

I am also interested in a way to implement the functionality of `nameof` in .NET 2.0 if that is possible.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329138/how-to-make-databinding-type-safe-and-support-refactoring

Comment: This issue is now solved at compile time! The [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) operator was implemented in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.6 and VS2015 in July 2015. The following answers are still valid for C# < 6.0.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This code basically does that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var propName = Nameof<SampleClass>.Property(e => e.Name);

        Console.WriteLine(propName);
    }
}

public class Nameof<T>
{
    public static string Property<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if(body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");
        return body.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

(Of course it is 3.5 code...)

Comment: Please note that there is a performance penalty. Expression objects are quite expensive to create. Calling a `Foo(Expression<Func<>>)` is 200 times slower than an old fashioned `Foo(string propName)`. Please vote for a [compile-time nameof operator](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2427047-add-nameof-operator-in-c-).

Comment: Note that this code must have been compiled in VS2015 in order to use Expression.Body

Answer (score 6):

While reshefm and Jon Skeet show the proper way to do this using expressions, it should be worth noting there's a cheaper way to do this for method names:

Wrap a delegate around your method, get the MethodInfo, and you're good to go. Here's an example:

```
private void FuncPoo()
{
}

...

// Get the name of the function
string funcName = new Action(FuncPoo).Method.Name;
```

Unfortunately, this works only for methods; it does not work for properties, as you cannot have delegates to property getter or setter methods. (Seems like a silly limitation, IMO.)

Comment: I agree. Silly limitation. I don't think it should be too hard for the compiler to understand whether it is the getter or the setter and let u use delegate it.

Answer (score 4):

The workaround is to use an expression tree, and to take that expression tree apart to find the relevant `MemberInfo`. There's slightly more detail and comment in [this note](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=69) (although not the code to pull out the member - that's in another SO question somewhere, I believe).

Unfortunately as expression trees don't exist in .NET 2.0, there's really no equivalent.

One solution to avoid typos is to have a set of accessors which fetch the relevant `PropertyInfo` for a particular property, and unit test them. That would be the only place which had the string in it. This would avoid duplication and make refactoring easier, but it's a bit draconian.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://imaginarydevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/10/compile-time-safe-databinding.html it references this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329138/how-to-make-databinding-type-safe-and-support-refactoring

Answer (score 4):

An extension to what reshefm did, that simplified the usage of the nameof() operator, and gives the names of methods and class members and methods as well:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides the <see cref="nameof"/> extension method that works as a workarounds for a nameof() operator, 
/// which should be added to C# sometime in the future.
/// </summary>
public static class NameOfHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string represantaion of a property name (or a method name), which is given using a lambda expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the <paramref name="obj"/> parameter.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProp">The type of the property (or the method's return type), which is used in the <paramref name="expression"/> parameter.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj">An object, that has the property (or method), which its name is returned.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">A Lambda expression of this pattern: x => x.Property <BR/>
    /// Where the x is the <paramref name="obj"/> and the Property is the property symbol of x.<BR/>
    /// (For a method, use: x => x.Method()</param>
    /// <returns>A string that has the name of the given property (or method).</returns>
    public static string nameof<T, TProp>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExp = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExp != null)
            return memberExp.Member.Name;

        MethodCallExpression methodExp = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodExp != null)
            return methodExp.Method.Name;

        throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression or a method call expression.", "expression");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string represantaion of a property name (or a method name), which is given using a lambda expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TProp">The type of the property (or the method's return type), which is used in the <paramref name="expression"/> parameter.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="expression">A Lambda expression of this pattern: () => x.Property <BR/>
    /// Where Property is the property symbol of x.<BR/>
    /// (For a method, use: () => x.Method()</param>
    /// <returns>A string that has the name of the given property (or method).</returns>
    public static string nameof<TProp>(Expression<Func<TProp>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExp = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExp != null)
            return memberExp.Member.Name;

        MethodCallExpression methodExp = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodExp != null)
            return methodExp.Method.Name;

        throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression or a method call expression.", "expression");
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string strObj = null;
        Console.WriteLine(strObj.nameof(x => x.Length)); //gets the name of an object's property.
        Console.WriteLine(strObj.nameof(x => x.GetType())); //gets the name of an object's method.
        Console.WriteLine(NameOfHelper.nameof(() => string.Empty)); //gets the name of a class' property.
        Console.WriteLine(NameOfHelper.nameof(() => string.Copy(""))); //gets the name of a class' method.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless someone changes their mind, the `nameof` operator looks like it's coming in C# 6. Here are the design meeting notes about it:

https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/552376

https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/552377

Comment: I've been waiting this for so long. So nice to see it being implemented.

Comment: And here is the official documentation for the [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) operator which did indeed become available in C# 6.0 (and Visual Studio 2015).

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the language in C# 6.0

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution is nice, simple and elegant.

However, building an expression tree is expensive, and I need the whole property path.

So I changed it a bit. It is not elegant at all, but it is simple and works well in most cases:

```
public static string Property<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
{
    var s = expression.Body.ToString();
    var p = s.Remove(0, s.IndexOf('.') + 1);
    return p;
}
```

Example:

```
? Nameof<DataGridViewCell>.Property(c => c.Style.BackColor.A);
"Style.BackColor.A"
```

Comment: I created the generic method:

public static string PropertyPath<T,TProp>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
        {
            var s = expression.Body.ToString();
            var p = s.Remove(0, s.IndexOf('.') + 1);
            return p;
        }

Comment: From the documentation for the [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) operator (new to C# 6.0), in the section **Remarks**: *If you need to get the fully-qualified name, you can use the* ***typeof*** *expression along with* ***nameof*** *.*

Answer (score 1):

The answer from reshefm is pretty good, but this is a little bit simpler API IMO:

Usage example:
`NameOf.Property(() => new Order().Status)`

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace AgileDesign.Utilities
{
public static class NameOf
{
    ///<summary>
    ///  Returns name of any method expression with any number of parameters either void or with a return value
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name = "expression">
    ///  Any method expression with any number of parameters either void or with a return value
    ///</param>
    ///<returns>
    ///  Name of any method with any number of parameters either void or with a return value
    ///</returns>
    [Pure]
    public static string Method(Expression<Action> expression)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(expression != null);

        return ( (MethodCallExpression)expression.Body ).Method.Name;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///  Returns name of property, field or parameter expression (of anything but method)
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name = "expression">
    ///  Property, field or parameter expression
    ///</param>
    ///<returns>
    ///  Name of property, field, parameter
    ///</returns>
    [Pure]
    public static string Member(Expression<Func<object>> expression)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(expression != null);

        if(expression.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            return ((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand).Member.Name;
        }
        return ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
    }
  }
}
```

Full code is here:
http://agiledesignutilities.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b76cefa4234a#GeneralPurpose/NameOf.cs