# Get property name from class

Tags: c#, reflection

I need  property name in my app and I use next code to get it

```
string PropertyName =SomeClass.GetType().GetProperty("Category").Name;
```

But I think that is bad idea. Because I use web service classes and I dont know when property names can be changed. This code give me exception only in runtime. But if I write something like this SomeClassInstance.Property.GetProperyName i get exception in moment of compilation and repair this problem.
Is it possible to get property name dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very neat solution here: [Workaround for lack of 'nameof' operator in C# for type-safe databinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301809/workarounds-for-nameof-operator-in-c-typesafe-databinding)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Expression<Func<string>> expression = () => Sample.Foo;
 MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
 string name = body.Member.Name;
```

Where Sample.Foo is your property
So that would be SomeClass.Category.Name