# AutoMapper: map DTO back to domain object with child objects

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

Let's say I have two objects I'd like to map:

```
// Domain objects
public class MyDomainObject
{
    public string SimpleText { get; set; }
    public int SimpleNumber { get; set; }
    public MySubObject ComplexValue { get; set; }
}

public class MySubObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// DTOs
public class MyDto
{
    public string SimpleText { get; set; }
    public int SimpleNumber { get; set; }
    public int ComplexValueId { get; set; }
    public string ComplexValueName { get; set; }
}

// Mapping config
Mapper.CreateMap<MyDomainObject, MyDto>();
```

Ths will work fine without extra configuration because AutoMapper will look at **camelcasing** and drill down.

Now I'd like to **map the DTO back to the domain object**:
`Mapper.Map<MyDto, MyDomainObject>(dto, domainObj);`

What would the best/simplest mapping **configuration** be to achieve it?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145062/using-automapper-to-unflatten-a-dto