# Is projection by convention possible with AutoMapper?

Tags: automapper, automapper-2

I have the following data returned from my database:

```
Number, AddressStreet, AddressCity, AddressState
```

My domain objects are as follows:

```
public class Order
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public String Number { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String State { get; set; }
    public String Street { get; set; }
}
```

Using the built-in DataReaderMapper, mapping from the IDataReader containing the database data is simple except I can't get the Address object populated.

Ideally, I'd like to use DynamicMap as follows:

```
var order = Mapper.DynamicMap<Order>(dataReader);
```

When I do this, order.Number is populated but order.Address is null.  When I create a new instance of the Address class in the Order constructor it's not null (as expected) but none of the properties are set.

I've tried:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Order>()
      .ForMember(target => target.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
```

and changed the column names to simple "Street", "City" and "State" with no luck.

I've tried:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Address>();
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Order>()
      .ForMember(target => target.Address, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
```

and all combinations there of.  I even specified ForMembers for each property on Address. Nothing has worked.

I know AutoMapper supports flattening by convention, I can only assume from what I am finding that projection by convention (where it recognizes that AddressStreet should be mapped to Address.Street) is not possible.  Am I wrong?

How do I get the above example working???

**UPDATE**

We've been able to get it to work using:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Order>()
    .ForMember(target => target.Address,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<Address>(src)));
```

Seems kinda cludgy, though.

Comment: You're not wrong when asserting that "projection by convention" (or unflattening) is not possible.
Take a look at this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145062/using-automapper-to-unflatten-a-dto

Comment: Yea, I tried the different ways described in that article but none of them allowed by the map the child object from the data reader.