# AutoMapper - Nested mapping whilst preserving selected child properties

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, automapper, automapper-2

So i have this;

```
public class Parent
{
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
  public Child ChildProperty { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
  public string ChildProperty { get; set; }
  public string OtherChildProperty { get; set; }
}
public class Flat
{
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
  public string ChildProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And then I do this;

```
Flat source = new Flat { SomeProperty = "test", ChildProperty = "test" };
Parent dest = GetParentFromDataContext();

Mapper.Map<Flat,Parent>(source,dest);
```

Then my expectation is that `dest.ChildProperty.OtherChildProperty` is still set to whatever it was when it was pulled from the datacontext.  However I'm struggling to do this.

If I `CreateMap` as so, then I get a "must resolve to top-level member" exception;

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Flat,Parent>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Parent.ChildProperty.ChildProperty,
    options => options.MapFrom(source => source.ChildProperty))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Parent.ChildProperty.OtherChildProperty,
    options => options.Ignore());
```

However if I do the following, then the `new Child {}` replaces the `Child` pulled from the datacontext essentially clearing `OtherChildProperty`;

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Flat,Parent>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Child
    options => options.MapFrom(source => new Child { ChildProperty = source.ChildProperty } ));
```

How can i map this and preserve the child properties I wish to ignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inelegant, but this works;

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Flat,Parent>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildProperty, options => options.Ignore());
Mapper.CreateMap<Flat,Child>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.OtherChildProperty, options => options.Ignore());

Mapper.Map<Flat,Parent>(source,dest);
Mapper.Map<Flat,Child>(source,dest.Child);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reverse flattening process with automapper and that is just wrong tool for the job. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145062/using-automapper-to-unflatten-a-dto) SO question.