# Automapper DTO to Entity Nested Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, dto

I have entities:

```
public class Person
 {
   //properties
   public virtual State State { get; set; }
 }

 public class State
 {
       //properties
       public int StateId { get; set; }
       public string StateName { get; set; }
       public virtual Address Address{ get; set; }
 }

public class Address
 {
       //properties
       public int AddressId { get; set; }
       public string City{ get; set; }
       public int PostalCode { get; set; }       
 }
```

And i have a flatten DTO called PersonDetails

```
public class PersonDetails
 {
       //properties
       public string City { get; set; }
       public string StateName { get; set; }
       public int PostalCode { get; set; }       
 }
```

When I do the mapping it works but it creates a new State and Adress for the Person entity.

How would I use AutoMapper to map from `PersonDetails` to `PersonEntity`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using AutoMapper to unflatten a DTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145062/using-automapper-to-unflatten-a-dto)

Comment: See also the related: on the linked post