# How can I create an Automapper extension method to perform a mapping on all properties of a certain type?

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to create an Automapper extension method that performs a custom mapping on all properties of a certain type. Here is some pseudocode demonstrating what I want:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> UnflattenMembers<TSource, TDestination>
        (this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map)
    {
        foreach (property of the TSource Class)
        {
            if (property is of Type SpecialClass)
            {
                map.ForMember(dest => dest.property, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

I want to do this to achieve a generic implementation of sydneyos's answer to this question: [Using AutoMapper to unflatten a DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145062/using-automapper-to-unflatten-a-dto).

E.g., Instead of doing this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestClass>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src )))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MailingInfo, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src )))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Calendar, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src )))
    etc...;
```

I want to to this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestClass>().UnflattenMembers();
```

Comment: I think you could transform pseudocode to real code using reflection.

Comment: Is `opt.MapFrom( src => src )` actually working? shouldn't you be using `opt.MapFrom( src => src.Address )` for example?

Comment: Can you give an example of a source and destination types?