# How can I get the name of an ICollection<> property from a reference to the contained type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, properties

I have type references `A` and `B` but I want the name of the `ICollection<A>` which is a property of `B`. How can I get the collection name "BunchOfX" if I only have the two types?

```
public class X
{
}

public class Y
{
   public virtual ICollection<X> BunchOfX { get; set; }
}
```

I need something that can give me the property name "BunchOfX" when all I have is the type references A and B. Let's say A will reference the type that the ICollection<> holds, and B will reference the type the ICollection<> is defined on.

**The Real Code**

```
var entityType = Type.GetType(nameSpace + "." + entityTypeName);
var foreignType = Type.GetType(nameSpace + "." + foreignTypeName);
var names = foreignType.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => typeof(ICollection<entityType>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
    .Select(p => p.Name);
var foreignCollectionName = names.FirstOrDefault();
```

entityType gives `"type or namespace unknown"` when it is in the <>

**Solution based on Jon and Ani's replies**

```
var foreignCollectionName = foreignType.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => typeof(ICollection<>)
        .MakeGenericType(entityType)
        .IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
    .Select(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You'll most likely have to do it through reflection, or are you asking for specific code to find it?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to call `Method(b.BunchOfA)` and be able to have `Method` know that it was passed in a property called `BunchOfA`?

Comment: @R0MANARMY I figured reflection, but I am a total beginner with .NET - specific code would be ideal. If it is very complicated then being pointed in the right direction would also be helpful. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: possible duplicate of [workarounds for nameof() operator in C#: typesafe databinding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301809/workarounds-for-nameof-operator-in-c-typesafe-databinding)

Comment: @Gabe I'm not sure what you mean. But I think I asked the question the wrong way so I edited it. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 4):

You'd need to look through the properties with reflection. The easiest way to do this is using LINQ:

```
var names = typeOfB.GetProperties()
                   .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(desiredPropertyType))
                   .Select(p => p.Name);
```

Comment: The PropertyType of the PropertyInfo ICollection<A> is the type 'A' ? Not just some collection type? Am I misunderstanding? It seems too easy. Thanks!

Comment: @Benjamin: No, the property type will be `ICollection<A>` - that's what it's declared as. The type of the *value* returned from the property would be some concrete implementation, but the type of the property itself is `ICollection<A>`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I think I botched this question though. I will only have run-time references to the two types. I will not have the type of the collection, only a reference to the type the collection property is designed to hold. I will have a reference to the type the collection is ON, and a reference to the type the collection can "collect". I didn't know how to ask this better. Does that make sense? Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Benjamin: Then I think your predicate in the `Where` clause should be: `p => typeof(ICollection<A>).IsAssignableFrom(p.propertyType)` or similar. Or maybe `IEnumerable<A>`?

Comment: Interesting, I will try it out.

Comment: @Benjamin: A reference to the type itself, or a reference to an instance of the type? It would *really* help if you'd give a short but complete example...

Comment: @Ani I get the error "The type or namespace name 'A' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" - A is from Type.GetType(string) and debugs ok but as soon as I put it in between the <> in the ICollection<> then it is not recognized.

Comment: @Benjamin: It's far too unclear *exactly* what you've got, because you haven't shown us the code. Give us a complete example and it'll be easy to work out.

Comment: @Jon I pasted in my actual code above. I can give more if it is needed. I can never figure out what is helpful to provide with my questions so thanks for telling me.

Comment: @Benjamin: Looking at your update, looks like you want to replace the `typeof(..)` bit with `typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(entityType).IsAssignableFrom(p.propertyType)`. Goodness knows why you are playing around with so many strings though...

Comment: @Ani it works! Thank you to both of you. I will try to clean up the original post. If you have any advice regarding "so many strings" I certainly welcome it. My background is lame QBASIC screensavers, this is my first .NET project. Thanks again.