# How to auto-generate early bound properties for Entity specific (ie Local) Option Set text values?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

After spending a year working with the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk` namespace, I just discovered yesterday the `Entity.FormattedValues` property contains the text value for Entity specific (ie Local) Option Set texts.

The reason I didn't discover it before, is there is no early bound method of getting the value.  i.e. `entity.new_myOptionSet` is of type `OptionSetValue` which only contains the `int` value.  You have to call entity.FormattedValues["new_myoptionset"] to get the `string` text value of the `OptionSetValue`.

Therefore, I'd like to get the crmsrvcutil to auto-generate a text property for local option sets.  i.e. Along with `Entity.new_myOptionSet` being generated as it currently does, `Entity.new_myOptionSetText` would be generated as well.

I've looked into the [Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.ICodeGenerationService](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh560358.aspx), but that looks like it is mostly for specifying what `CodeGenerationType` something should be...

Is there a way supported way using CrmServiceUtil to add these properties, or am I better off writing a custom app that I can run that can generate these properties as a partial class to the auto-generated ones?

### Edit - Example of the code that I would like to be generated

Currently, whenever I need to access the text value of a OptionSetValue, I use this code:

```
var textValue = OptionSetCache.GetText(service, entity, e => e.New_MyOptionSet);
```

The option set cache will use the `entity.LogicalName`, and the property expression to determine the name of the option set that I'm asking for.  It will then query the SDK using the `RetrieveAttriubteRequest`, to get a list of the option set int and text values, which it then caches so it doesn't have to hit CRM again.  It then looks up the int value of the `New_MyOptionSet` of the entity and cross references it with the cached list, to get the text value of the OptionSet.

Instead of doing all of that, I can just do this (assuming that the entity has been retrieved from the server, and not just populated client side):

```
var textValue = entity.FormattedValues["new_myoptionset"];
```

but the "new_myoptionset" is no longer early bound.  I would like the early bound entity classes that gets generated to also generate an extra "Text" property for OptionSetValue properties that calls the above line, so my entity would have this added to it:

```
public string New_MyOptionSetText {
    return this.GetFormattedAttributeValue("new_myoptionset"); // this is a protected method on the Entity class itself...
}
```

Comment: Can't you just call `.ToString()` on the enum value (e.g. `SalesOrderState.Invoiced.ToString()`), or are you talking about something else?

Comment: @PeterMajeed Calling ToString on the Option Set generated enum doesn't work all the time (what if the text value was "Ready to Ship", then enum.ToString() would be "ReadytoShip".  Another one that wouldn't work is say "A+").  I've currently written code for an interface for the CrmServiceUtil that ensures that all optionset text values are valid C# enum names, so I know that method won't work.

Comment: I think it's an excellent question given the lack of documentation for CrmSvcUtil. Still, I don't see why you'd need an early bound version of the string value of an option set when you can access the string value via a formatted value. Do you think you can share a few lines of code/pseudocode that demonstrates your end purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of the [CRM Early Bound Generator](https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools/releases) includes a `Fields` struct that that contains the field names.  This allows accessing the FormattedValues to be as simple as this:

```
var textValue = entity.FormattedValues[MyEntity.Fields.new_MyOptionSet];
```

You could create a new property via an interface for the CrmSvcUtil, but that's a lot of work for a fairly simple call, and I don't think it justifies creating additional properties.

Comment: I know it is a long time ago, but I'm not seeing this `Fields` struct. Is this a configurable option?

Comment: It's the option "Generate Attribute Name Consts"

Answer (score 0):

Could you utilize the CrmServiceUtil extension that will generate **enums** for your OptionSets and then add your new_myOptionSetText property to a partial class that compares the int value to the enums and [returns the enum string](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-tostring)

Comment: I should have read your comment more carefully...looks like you already considered this.

Comment: Actually with the formatted values, I don't have to compare the int value to anything.  It actually contains the text value of the option set value.  What the question is asking is, is there a way to override property creation using an interface with crmsrvcutil, that allows me to add an additional early bound property for the option set value text...

Comment: Good question!  That would be a nice extension point if you are able to do that.

Comment: I'm thinking I'm going to have to write a console app that runs against the generated code, determines if each option set is global or local, then generates partial classes with the local option set value text properties.  It shouldn't be too hard...

Comment: Using reflection or RegEx (text)?  Would the MetaDataService have that info?  With my MSFT Currency issue, I was reintroduced to the Attributes table...SQL might be a quick/dirty plan B

Comment: The Reflection to get the properties that are OptionSetValues is easy.    We usually don't give Database rights out to users, so I'll probably stick to a couple SDK calls...

Answer (score 0):

Again, I think specifically for this case, getting `CrmSvcUtil.exe` to generate the code you want is a great idea, but more generally, you can access the property name via reflection using an approach similar to the accepted answer @ [workarounds for nameof() operator in C#: typesafe databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301809/workarounds-for-nameof-operator-in-c-typesafe-databinding).

```c#
var textValue = entity.FormattedValues["new_myoptionset"];
// becomes
var textValue = entity.FormattedValues
[
    // renamed the class from Nameof to NameOf
    NameOf(Xrm.MyEntity).Property(x => x.new_MyOptionSet).ToLower()
];
```

Comment: The code for the properties should be autogenerated, which means that having a "hardcoded" string is totally acceptable.  Also, not every option set value property would have a corresponding text property, because not every option set is a local one.  Therefore, even though this would be an "earlybound" sort of method of getting the property, it doesn't help at all in aiding developers in seeing what properties are truly available to them.

Comment: @Daryl: Not sure if the distinction between global and local option sets is a significant one, since ultimately all global option sets are stored locally and can be accessed similarly using the `FormattedValues` property. So far as seeing which properties are really available, if I understand correctly, this is a problem that can be solved I believe by cross-checking the list of entity `Attributes` against reflected `Xrm` properties, which would need to be checked when using the `FormattedValues` array anyway.