# How to get the property name with out reflection in c#

Tags: c#

How to get the Property Name as a string?

For example:

```
Public int PropertyValue{get;set;}
```

Now i want to get the PropertyValue as a string with out reflection and with out foreach PropertyInfo

Comment: Why dont you want to use reflection?

Comment: if i use reflection i can get all the meta data of the property right

Comment: Could you post a minimal pseudo-code, which will give us some context?

Comment: Here you go: the property name is `"PropertyValue"` - absolutely no reflection. Now; if you provide some context, maybe it'll make more sense?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression - shows how to get property name from expression almost matching your "don't wnat to..." requirements (+1 to Stian Standahl answer which show slightly shorter version).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here:
[Workaround for lack of 'nameof' operator in C# for type-safe databinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301809/workarounds-for-nameof-operator-in-c-typesafe-databinding)

Where @reshefm had this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var propName = Nameof<SampleClass>.Property(e => e.Name);

        Console.WriteLine(propName);
    }
}

public class Nameof<T>
{
    public static string Property<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if(body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");
        return body.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)